# Поиск файлов по поисковому слову

Tags: php

Помогите написать функцию, которая выведет список файлов из директории, которые содержат искомое слово. Директория и искомое слово задаются как параметры функции.

Comment: Покажите что вы сделали для этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function f($dir, $name, $exclude_dir = true) {
return array_filter(scandir($dir), function ($i) use ($exclude_dir, $name) {
    if ($exclude_dir && is_dir($i)) return false;
    return substr_count($i, $name);
} );}
```

Comment: 0xdef, вы проверяли работает ф-ция или нет? Просто у меня она выдает ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$exclude_dir'  ...

Comment: Pull request: `function () use $exclude_dir {` => `function ($e) use ($exclude_dir, $name) {`; `substr_count($dir, $name)` => `substr_count($e, $name)`.

Comment: Заработала, но список найденных файлов не выводит. Нужно еще результат либо print_r в тегах <pre></pre>, либо имплоудить результат и выводить списком... Это еще добавит пару строк кода. Но тогда все мудреность и сложность функции лишняя. Может как-то проще вывести список найденных файлов?

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? функция список файлов возвращает в массиве. Можете его вывести как хотите, любым удобным образом.

Comment: @Eugene, уважаемый, Вы уже и ТЗ клепаете???

Comment: Нет, ТЗ не клепаю! Это начальное условие было. Никого не хотел обидеть... Извините, если что ... Решил своими силами уже. В любом случае огромное спасибо, 0xdef !!!